# mkfs.ext4: Invalid argument on raspberry pi

Tags: partition, raspberry-pi, ssd

Trying to partition my SSD with this

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda
```

I get the following error:

```
Creating journal (262144 blocks): mkfs.ext4: Invalid argument
while trying to create journal
```

Any clue why there is an invalid argument?

Also, after this, the drive is not visible anymore with fdisk -l.
I have to reboot to see it again.

Comment: You shouldn’t be making a filesystem on the drive but rather on a partition on the drive. If you wish to format the entire drive with an ext4 filesystem, wipe the partition table and create a new partition using `fdisk`, then use `mkfs` on that partition.

Comment: `sda` represents the entire drive while you probably want to format a specific partition instead. This operation most likely has destroyed the partition table, so you need to repartition it again and format.

Comment: Got it! That was an easy fix! Thanks to both of you!